# skip methods from tested class when using JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have the following situation. I have a class

```
A  {

    public void setProps() {
        // setting propertis

        makeSomeWeirdConfigs();

        //setting another properties

    }

    private void makeSomeWeirdConfigs() {
    // making configs
    }

    public Props getProps() {
    //getting properties
    }
}
```

Now I want to check with the help of JUnit test case if the properties are properly set by using method `setProps()` and then getting the properties with `getProps()`.

The problem is this method `makeSomeWeirdConfigs()` in the middle of the `setProps()`, which when executed without the proper environment cause a lot of exceptions, so the props below this method are not set.

Also this method tries to do dangerous things for example executing some scripts etc. So my question is is it possible to skip this method `makeSomeWeirdConfigs()` somehow in the JUnit test case, so only `setProps()` and `getProps()` are executed.

The original class A should not be changed.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Powermock to mock the private method

Comment: can you provide example

Comment: Here you find an example: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Original class should not be changed" - then you are seeking something mocking, byte code fiddling, AOP.

If you made `makeSomeWeirdConfig` protected, you could override the method and test a child class. The same with testing an extra flag.

If you could put the code in a delegator even better towards sound code.

```
class SomeWeirdConfig {
    void makeSomeWeirdConfigs() { ... }
}

SomeWeirdConfig delegate = new SomeWeirdConfig();

public void initTest() { delegate = null; }

private void makeSomeWeirdConfigs() {
    if (delegate != null) {
        delegate.makeSomeWeirdConfigs();
    }
}
```

Then the test could disable the setter.